# How to create a required property and used it for an API?

Tags: node.js

I'm new to using API and i'm currently building a site and i want to accept payments, i get the documentation but how can i do this in easy and noob way? like how and where do i put the payload and how do i access said payload?, thanks in advance guys

**usage**

```
import Paymongo from 'paymongo';

// Retrieve the secret key from your paymongo 
// dashboard under developers tab.
const paymongo = new Paymongo(process.env.SECRET_KEY);
```

**Payment Method - create**

```
/**
 * These are the required properties
 * @param {Object} data The payload.
 * @param {Object} data.attributes Payload attributes.
 * @param {string} data.attributes.type The type of payment method. The possible value is card for now.
 * @param {string} data.attributes.details.card_number Credit/Debit Card number of the PaymentMethod.
 * @param {number} data.attributes.details.exp_month Expiry month of the Credit/Debit Card.
 * @param {number} data.attributes.details.exp_year Expiry year of the Credit/Debit Card.
 * @param {string} data.attributes.details.cvc CVC of the Credit/Debit Card.
 */
const result = await paymongo.paymentMethods.create(data);
```

**Payload**

```
{
  data: {
    attributes: {
      type: 'card' // The only available type for now is 'card'.
      details: {
        card_number: '000000000000',
        exp_month: 02,
        exp_year: 23,
        cvc: '123',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The payload is not something you receive. But something you send. It's the data of the credit card that your users enter into a form when making the payment. When it's validated by the payment provider the result contains information on whether the payment was accepted. Your best shot at getting this to work is the paymongo documentation though.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.paymongo.com/docs/accepting-cards gives a very good guide on how to setup credit card paypment on Paymongo.

Simply put, you have to collect credit card data from your frontend and create a payment method and a payment intent.
Afterwards, attach the payment method to the payment intent including a redirect URL. You will receive a URL that you should then redirect the user to. After the user authorizes the payments, he will be redirected to the URL you've included in attaching the method to the payment intent.

All of the endpoint you need are here https://developers.paymongo.com/reference